# useLegacyAuth=1 in MySQL Workbench 6.3 (Win x64) fails with Wrong type passed, expected sql::SQLString

Tags: mysql, workbench

There's no way to make this work.

I tried all kind of combinations, all failing.

```
useLegacyAuth=1
useLegacyAuth="1"
useLegacyAuth='1'
useLegacyAuth=`1`
```

Answer (score 1):

Old one but still useful, figured I would update with what I know. 
if you put quotes around the whole thing it should work.
"useLegacyAuth=1"